# How to put PHP array 'x' literally in array 'y'

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what's going on, it seems like a have a PHP beginner issue. I want to put the content of the $moduleDetail array (key-value pairs) literally in another array ($url). Here's my attempt:

```
    $moduleDetail = array();

    if (isset($menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'])) {
        $moduleDetail['slug'] = $menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'];
    }

    $url = $this->Html->link(
        $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
        array(
            'controller' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller'],
            'action' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleAction']['action'],
            'pagePath' => $pagePathString,
            Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller']) . 'Controller' => Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['slug']),
            $moduleDetail,
            'full_base' => true
        ),
        array(
            'title' => $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
            'escape' => false
        )
    );
```

I thought the output of the variable should become something like this:

```
$moduleDetail = array();

if (isset($menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'])) {
    $moduleDetail['slug'] = $menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'];
}

$url = $this->Html->link(
    $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
    array(
        'controller' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller'],
        'action' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleAction']['action'],
        'pagePath' => $pagePathString,
        Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller']) . 'Controller' => Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['slug']),
        'slug' => 'boomerang',
        'full_base' => true
    ),
    array(
        'title' => $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
        'escape' => false
    )
);
```

But it constantly returns this error:

> Warning (2): rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given

Any ideas? I hope my question won't be downvoted as I can't find a simular question on Google or even on StackOverflow ('Questions that may already have your answer'). Perhaps my search keywords aren't good enough? :)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is add the key 'slug' to the existing array with the value `$menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug']`. But what you are actually doing is adding an *array* with the key 'slug' and value `$menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug']` to the array. So what you are creating is this:

```
array(
    'controller' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller'],
    'action' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleAction']['action'],
    'pagePath' => $pagePathString,
    Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller']) . 'Controller' => Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['slug']),
    array(
        'slug' => 'boomerang'
    )
    'full_base' => true
),
```

Presumably the `url()` function is not expecting nested arrays which is why you're getting the error you're getting.

You don't need to create a `$moduleDetail` array. All you need to do is add the key with the correct value:

```
$url = $this->Html->link(
    $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
    array(
        'controller' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller'],
        'action' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleAction']['action'],
        'pagePath' => $pagePathString,
        Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller']) . 'Controller' => Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['slug']),
        'slug' => $menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'],
        'full_base' => true
    ),
    array(
        'title' => $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
        'escape' => false
    )
);
```

Edit: if you need to conditionally add things to the array, it's best to build it outside of the function call:

```
$params = array(
    'controller' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller'],
    'action' => $menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleAction']['action'],
    'pagePath' => $pagePathString,
    Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['controller']) . 'Controller' => Inflector::variable($menuItem['Page']['ModuleActionModuleController']['ModuleController']['slug']),
    'full_base' => true
);
if (isset($menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'])) {
    $params['slug'] = $menuItem['Page']['module_detail_slug'];
}

$url = $this->Html->link(
    $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
    $params,
    array(
        'title' => $menuItem['MenuPageLink']['title'],
        'escape' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer! The problem is that I don't want the 'slug' key in the $url array when the value of that 'slug' key is empty. That's why I am using that $moduleDetail-variable :)

Comment: Updated my answer with another example.